# Reading a portion of data file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data file (data.dat) like this,

Range

```
1  12.0100 # c3
2  12.0100 # ca
3  16.0000 # os
4  12.0100 # cc
5   1.0080 # ho
6  16.0000 # oh
7  12.0100 # cx
```

Pair corela

```
1     0.109400     3.399670
2     0.086000     3.399670
3     0.170000     3.000012
4     0.086000     3.399670
5     0.000000            0
6     0.210400     3.066473
7     0.086000     3.399670
```

Angle ter

```
1   318.300000     1.518400 # c3 cx
2   321.000000     1.515600 # c3 ca
```

I want to read only the portion under "Pair corela" using python. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Please don't change your question mid-flight, it's against site guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get two index values corresponding to the start and end of the data you want to read.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data.dat') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if 'Pair corela' in line:
            i = idx
        elif 'Angle ter' in line:
            j = idx
            break
```

Now, use `read_csv` with `skiprows` and `nrows`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.dat', skiprows=i, nrows=(j - i))
```

Comment: @SupriyoNaskar No, thank you. You asked a different question, and I've answered that. If you have a different question, please open a new thread.